Export data to CSV using Teradata BTEQ
I am trying to export data in CSV format using BTEQ, via Windows command line or batch.
When trying I get an output in a fixed width columns format or an even stranger format in only one column.
What I want is simply something looking like:
Field 1;Field 2
aaa;1
bbb;1

Here is my bteq script
.EXPORT DIF FILE=xxx;
.SET SEPARATOR ';';
.RUN FILE=xxx;
.LOGOFF;

xxx stands for the actual paths. The .logon statement with the server/user/password are in the cmd statement.
Thank you for your help.

Have a look at this answer using CSV. Another function to create a comma-delimitted list is the PACK table operator.
Of course the best solution for a larger number of rows is using TPT Export.
